# Why is bubble wrap so fun?

Tags: well-being, sensation, psychoacoustics

Popping bubble wrap can be a lot of fun and is said to relieve stress. How does it have these effects? Is it to do with the popping sound, or the physicality? How effective are substitutes such as software programs where users click on virtual bubble wrap?

Comment: I suspect software programs are highly ineffective as a substitute because they don't provide tactile feedback.

Comment: This question is primarily opinion-based and too broad to answer